# Character Set ISO8859_1 is not Installed

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird-3.0, firebird-embedded

I have created a C# windows application which is updating a database from Firebird Server to SQL Server. It was successfully running in Visual studio 2015, but when I published(deployed) it and installed in system or others system and when I run the application, I am getting error like this `Character Set ISO8859_1 is not installed`.

I have searched on google, and found it's a problem with `fbintl` not properly added to solution explorer. I have removed and added properly in a folder and also I have reinstalled Firebird server. Still I'm getting the same error.

What do I have to do? Is there anything I'm missing? I am using latest versions of Firebird 3.0.3(64bit) and firebird-embedded 2.5.8 and below image was my solution explorer.

[image]

Comment: If you have Firebird server, then why are you using Firebird Embedded? And please be specific with the information provided: post the full exception stacktrace, and the full version information. Saying _"I am using latest versions"_ is not very helpful. Please specify the full versions (especially as you seem to be using a Firebird 2.5.x embedded, not a Firebird 3.0 embedded). In any case, have you double checked if the fbintl is actually deployed with your application?

Comment: specify connection charset to be one of the list supported by your FB version

Comment: thanks for reply of "Mark Rotteveel", My firebird database extension was .CMP so that i am using Firebird-embedded and my firebird version was 3.0.3 (64bit) and firebird-embedded version was 2.5.6 (32bit) using them i have successfully running VS 2015 but its not running when i deploy the application i have checked 'fbintl.dll' is also deployed.and also checked with other version FB-embedded(3.0 and 2.5.8) versions i am getting error 'Unsupported On-Disk Structure'.

Comment: `.CMP` is not a 'normal' Firebird extension, and a Firebird embedded can open all database the normal Firebird of that same version can open. A 3.0.x Firebird can't open Firebird 2.5 or earlier database, and a 2.5.x can open Firebird 1.0 - 2.5 databases. You can't get an ODS error with 2.5.8 if that same database opens fine with 2.5.6. The simplest solution may be to install Firebird server 2.5.8 instead of using Firebird embedded. In any case, I suggest you take your question to the Firebird .net provider mailing list, that will be a more suitable place for troubleshooting.